# VPN connection drops after ~23 minutes

Tags: windows, vpn

I have set up VPN server (PPTP) on Windows Server 2012, I connect as a client from a Windows 7 PC and after roughly 23 minutes the connection drops, redials and connects fine.

- There are no connection limits on the server side.
- I have tried with dynamic dns and directly with the public IP, the result is the same.
- I login to the VPN with local account.
- Windows firewall is disabled on client side, Kaspersky Internet Security is installed
- Connection also drops from other PC's in the same network, though I have not tested connecting from another place that uses different router (maybe its the router)